# Ionic 3 prod release build issue with intellij-core-26.0.1

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I am creating release APK using the following versions : 
node - 8.12.0
gradle - 4.10.2
ionic CLI - 4.0.5
Cordova - 8.0.0

When I run the

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

I am getting the following error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
   > Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jar
```

When I place the "intellij-core-26.0.1" URL in browser, its showing status 404.

Anyone, Please suggest

Comment: Try to build release apk from android studio.

Comment: @Naveen I am building this APK as part of jenkins JOB. I need to resolve in jenkins job

Comment: This has started happening to me today! It must be a recent change.

Comment: @keldar Yes, I got this error today. But I didn't find any solution

Comment: No solution yet it seems. The issue looks to be that the [articfactory](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.android.tools.external.com-intellij%3Aintellij-core/26.0.1#files/com%2Fandroid%2Ftools%2Fexternal%2Fcom-intellij%2Fintellij-core%2F26.0.1) got updated with a new version... but the new version is missing the jar file..
[missing jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wafZ4.png)

Comment: Another link to same issue on ionic forums: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-pro-package-failed-after-successful-deploy/145355
(maybe you will find solution later)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that the problem started early today.

There's a few things that could work:

**The step that worked for me was:**

Edit "*\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle*" instead "*\platforms\android\build.gradle*" and put jcenter() after maven… as posted [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-pro-package-failed-after-successful-deploy/145355/14?u=lucasmds)

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
}
```

**You can try:**

Edit '*platforms/android/build.gradle*', you can see more [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build/132808), as pointed by 'netexpo', [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-pro-package-failed-after-successful-deploy/145355/12?u=lucasmds), in the Ionic forum.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Another one:**

Posted by MeterMoDev [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-pro-package-failed-after-successful-deploy/145355/16?u=lucasmds)

> Was able to build as well but did the following:
>
> Closed Android Studio also had VS closed.
>   Removed the Android platform.
>   Add the Android platform again.
>   Before running any builds open up the \platforms\android\build.gradle and edit the repositories like @netexpo recommended, and save the file. Open up your project in Android Studio waited for studio do sync the gradle file, it downloaded a couple of items. After the sync process was completed the file had been build.

```
 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 9):

ionic cordova platform remove android

ionic cordova platform add android@7.0.0

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: i agree this is the only solution that worked for me..thanks

Answer (score 7):

Go to `platforms/android/build.gradle`

Change this:

```
jcenter()    
maven {
   url "https://maven.google.com"
}
```

to

```
maven {
   url "https://maven.google.com"
}
jcenter()  //Just move this line
```

Comment: This is not possible in ionic build process because we are generating this file in every buid

Comment: My `build.gradle` file is like this already (with `jcenter()` at the bottom) and still doesn't work

Comment: This didn't work, however if you edit `platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle` and apply the fix that @RubenSala suggests above, it does. It worked for me :)

Answer (score 6):

Following on from Ruben Sala's suggestion, that didn't work for me. However, if you edit `platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle`, and apply the same fix Ruben suggests, it does.

I.e. change:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

To:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: this worked for me after 1 and half day trying, just make sure to edit the right file platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle not platforms/android/build.gradle, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the buildscript section in platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle from

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

to

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

fixed the issue for me. CLI and AS are building fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by editing \platforms\android\build.gradle file (line 39) to this:
    // Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.

```
 allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having issues in CI(Jenkins/Travis) instead of making manual changes every time build hook can be handy

create file at `config\before_compile_android.js`

```
module.exports = function(ctx) {
    'use strict';
    var fs = ctx.requireCordovaModule('fs'),
        path = ctx.requireCordovaModule('path'),
        deferral = ctx.requireCordovaModule('q').defer(),
        async = require('async');
    var platformRoot = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms/android');
    var gradleFiles = [path.join(platformRoot, 'build.gradle'), path.join(platformRoot, 'CordovaLib', 'build.gradle')];
    async.each(gradleFiles, function(f, cb) {
        fs.readFile(f, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                cb(err);
                return;
            }
            var result = data;
            if (data.indexOf("maven.google.com") >= 0) {
                console.log("Mirror already present in gradle file.\nSkipping...");
            }else{
                result = data.replace(/jcenter\(\)/g, 'maven{url "https://maven.google.com"}\njcenter()');
            }
            fs.writeFile(f, result, 'utf8', cb);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            deferral.reject();
        } else {
            deferral.resolve();
        }

    });
    return deferral.promise;
}
```

and in `config.xml` configure it for `before_compile`

```
<platform name="android">
   <hook src="config/before_compile_android.js" type="before_compile" />
...
```

**p.s.** I have not written entire script but modified it to resolve this issue

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```

This was for me what ended up working. Nothing else was doing the trick

ps. it installed android 7.1.4